# Django startproject doesn't create folder in virtualenv

Tags: python, django

I'm following the tutorial at http://djangobook.com/installing-django/ to setup Django. I created a new virtualenv and installed Django in it. I activate it through:

```
source env_mysite/bin/activate
```

After this I see (env_mysite) before my computer name in my terminal. Then I run

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

And here the tutorial says:

> This will create a mysite directory in your current directory (in this
>   case \env_mysite).

But my folder get created in my user root folder, not in my env_mysite folder. Why this is happening?

Comment: Instead of running "django-admin startproject mysite " what's the output of "pwd"?

Comment: "/Users/francesco". I assume this is to check the current working directory? But doesn't the virtualenv set the current directory to the root of virtualenv folder?

Comment: that's the point: you're not into env_mysite folder!

Comment: So everytime I activate my virtualenv I should also set the cd to env_mysite?

Comment: Why the hell would you create a project directory physically inside the virtualenv? Okay the website you linked hints at that, but it's really a bad idea in my opinion. The virtualenv is discardable. Your project is not.

Comment: Ok so maybe that's why my virtualenv doesn't set the cwd to the virtualenv root. I don't know it's the first time I work with virtualenvs, I assumed, reading the tutorial, that the project had to be inside it. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a project in venv folder (actually, you better not). You need virtual environment only to 'communicate' to your project via terminal (starting, migrating...)
Virtual environment contains needed tools to run your project, your project is not a part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Activating your virtualenv does not change your actual path. You have to navigate to your desired folder if you're not already there!